# Where is Android app data stored for Titanium key value pairs?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

In Titanium you can set and get data using:

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString("token", "")
```

A customer has an issue with a live app. I suspect it has something to do with how some of this data is set.

How can I find out what the values are for his phone? Where is it stored?
I assume it's in a file somewhere but where???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to retrieve the local properties in the file system of the phone itself. And even if that's possible I assume that those keys / values are encrypted.

The thing I know is that Appcelerator uses pre-reserved keys in local properties. Meaning that every time you build your app the key will be overridden. I often, instead of general key names, use more descriptive key names like 'api_token' or something like that.

I'm not sure if this helps but another thing that you could try is to log the incoming token on the server end and evaluate from there.